# How do I use ControlTemplate from another ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have

```
<!-- DERIVED1 - DERIVES FROM 'MOST BASE' -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="Derived1WidgetControlTemplate">
    <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource WidgetControlTemplateStyle}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExpandCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Some additional controls go here ... -->
            <Label Content="Blah blah" />

            <DockPanel>
                <!-- Content ... -->
                <ContentPresenter />
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- MOST BASE -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="WidgetControlTemplate">
    <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource WidgetControlTemplateStyle}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExpandCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Content ... -->
            <ContentPresenter />
        </DockPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Obviously the two templates are almost identical. What can I do to get rid of the repeating fragments?

Merging them into a single `ControlTemplate` and passing Dependency or Attached Properties is not an option - I need to have the two distinguishable control templates.

Comment: This interaction trigger is not easy to reuse, the only way I know, is by creating you own control in this case GroupBox, and stick it in it. Then each time you use this new control ,this is going to be a part of it. As for the dock panel. you can always have two dockpanels with keys, and use the one you need at given situation.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a Style, you *cannot* "override" only a part of a ControlTemplate or base a ControlTemplate on another ControlTemplate. You must (re)define the entire template as a whole.

What you possible could do is to move the GroupBox and all common parts of the template to a UserControl and include this UserControl in both templates, e.g.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.GroupBoxUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource WidgetControlTemplateStyle}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </GroupBox>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>

...

<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="TemplateA">
    <local:GroupBoxUserControl>
        <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
    </local:GroupBoxUserControl>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="TemplateB">
    <local:GroupBoxUserControl>
        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
    </local:GroupBoxUserControl>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Apart from this there is no way to avoid having to declare the same elements twice in the XAML markup I am afraid.